# VBA macro date format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with date format in my VBA macro. 
I am trying to create macro to analyze data log which I am getting from a robot which looks like this.

```
Counter_Red,"04/03/2019 12:54:19",3,1,43528537722.5347
```

At the beggining I need to split the data into separate columns before I can analyze them. 
When I use excel tool for splitting text into columns it works fine and I get expected result in format day.month.year.

```
04.3.2019  12:54:19
```

I created macro to do the split for me.

```
 Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 4), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1)),   _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

But when I use my VBA macro to do it, it always changes day and month so the resulting format is month.day.year.

```
3.4.2019  12:54:19
```

Can anyone please advice me how to fix it so my macro will give me correct date  format day.month.year?

Comment: Have you tired to set the format of the excel column ?

Comment: I don't think the date changes, it just gets formatted. `04/03/2019`is mm/dd/yyyy format and `3.4.2019 `is d.m.yyyy format I would guess. You can check this by explicit format the two dates `Format(date,"yyyy-mm-dd")`They should be the same, with same format.

Comment: Often the best way to make the sure the date is the one you think it is, is to use the `dd-mmm-yyyy` format (or any other format where the month is actually spelled out). `04.3.2019` may *look* like what you expect (though I think it's odd there is no leading zero before the `3`) but not *be* what you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much. The explicit change of format worked.

Answer (score 0):

J, they are right (above). Personally, if it's *small* amounts of data, I would use the *Split* function to place in an Array, then modify and output from there. It is true that Worksheet Functions will always be faster, and consume less resources than using Arrays (especially dynamic Array's), but perhaps:

```
Option Explicit

Function MakeDates()

Dim cellData As String
Dim arr_data() As String
Dim intArr As Integer

cellData = ActiveCell.Value

arr_data = Split(cellData, ",")

For intArr = 0 To UBound(arr_data) - 1
    'getting rid of double-quotes
    arr_data(intArr) = Replace(arr_data(intArr), """", "")
    'formatting date if applicable
    If IsDate(arr_data(intArr)) Then: _
    arr_data(intArr) = Format(arr_data(intArr), "dd-m-yyyy")
    'placing data on Sheet
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, intArr).Value = arr_data(intArr)
Next

End Function
```